# symfony2 monolog elastic logstash configuration

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, monolog

I've installed ruflin/elastica bundle to use with monolog in a Symfony 2.8 installation.
I was wondering if there would exist a tutorial to configure LogStash in order to use monolog generated logs.

At least I don't understand if basic input type is http, ftp or even udp.
Moreover, filter could be a defined one or should I create my own filter to capture standard symfony logs?

Comment: Maybe look into the filter for the logstash.conf file and define your patterns in an external conf file?